# Suddenly flutter start giving errors when i create new project and try to build it

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I upgraded flutter to the newest version, and then I wasn't able to build an app on my android phone, it forceshutdown of the project automatically. and these errors occur

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11391): Process: com.example.flutter_apps, PID: 11391
E/AndroidRuntime(11391): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flutter_apps/com.example.flutter_apps.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3752)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1818)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.getSplashScreenFromManifest(FlutterActivity.java:495)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.provideSplashScreen(FlutterActivity.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:301)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.createFlutterView(FlutterActivity.java:520)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:414)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(11391): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:202)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1150)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3736)
E/AndroidRuntime(11391):    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed earlier my flutter channel to master, and now I changed it to stable and all thing worked as expected
in cmd:
flutter channel stable

Comment: This comment resolved a difficult bug for me. Resources were unavailable in the release mode. The documentation for flutter_local_notifications pointed to R8 code shrinking but that did not solve the problem.